# ways to verify a process no longer has a controlling terminal

Tags: c, linux

The parent calls fork and has the child create a new session. I tried to verify that the child no longer has a controlling teminal.

```
...

if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {    /* child */
    if (setsid() < 0) {
        perror("setsid");
        exit(1);
    }
    char ch;
    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1) != 1) {
        printf("read error from controlling TTY, errno = %d\n", errno);
    }
    exit(0);
}
...    /* parent */
```

As we know, the error message should be printed but it didn't. Did I do something wrong? Is there any way to do this properly? Thanks.

Comment: That means sessions are created successfully. To conform that  you can print the process group of each process i.e. parent process and child process. For write one 'printf' statement before fork and one after 'setsid()' success condition. You can use 'getpgrp()' function to get the process group. If both group ids are different then setsid is successful and that's why you are not getting the errors.

Comment: @Optimus Yes. I did print the process ID, process group ID and session ID of both the parent and the child. And the output indicated that `setsid` returned succssfully. What I want to do now is to verify the child no longer has a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a working tty file descriptor does not imply a **controlling** terminal. You should be able to test for a controlling tty by opening `/dev/tty`. If you have a controlling tty, `/dev/tty` will act as an alias for it. If you don't, opening it should fail.

Another, less portable, method would be to read the 7th field in `/proc/self/stat`.